# Maintaining 3rd Party Django Apps as Git submodules

Tags: django, git, git-submodules, django-apps

I know this is perfectly possible and a lot of people already doing it, but my problem is slightly different and I couldn't figure out the solution yet:

Let a 3rd party Django App's structure as below:

- django-module

  - module

    - **init**.py
    - views.py
    - models.py
  - requirements.txt
  - setup.py

I want to bundle only the `module` directory as a submodule, because then I can access views.py file just by typing "module.views". If I import the django-module directory, I would have to write django-module.module.views to access the module files, which is not feasible.

My purpose is to modify the module and make pull requests occasionally to the original repository. Is there workflow that I can follow, or what are the best practices for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to keep the submodules exactly as they are.

Once you've added a 3rd party module to your app as a submodule, the next step is to make sure you add that "django-module" directory to your python path. As long as django-module is on your python path, you will be able to use the submodule as you usually would by typing "module.views" as you wish.

Comment: It sounds right. There are people suggesting creating a symlink to the module directory. Are there any important pitfalls of doing so?

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of any pitfalls of simlinking other than it's not common practice and others looking at your code might be confused. Typically you'll create a virtualenvironment for your project and if you have a lot of submodules or other things that need to be on your path, you'll have a script that you run that creates your virtualenvironment using commands like `add2virtualenv django-module`. This just feels cleaner to me, probably because I'm just used to this work flow.

Answer (score 3):

### Pip tips

Pip has support for [editable packages](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#the-requirements-file-format) and [retrieving packages with git](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#git), so you could create a virtualenv, use pip to install the packages, and update them using pip when you want.

So you could add:

```
-e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709#egg=MyProject
```

To your `requirements.txt` to retrieve that exact commit.

---

### Suggested workflow

I think that the best way to solve your issue is the following:

- Make a private fork of the package
- Edit the package in a specific development branch in the forked repository
- Use the package from your fork's development branch in your requirements file.
- When you feel like it, update the forked package where you're using it using pip.
- When you're ready to make a pull request, pull origin, rebase your working branch to origin/master, and make the pull request from the master branch of your fork.

This means you have three places where the code is present:

- The original repo (where you don't have access)
- Your forked repo (where you work on your fork)
- Wherever pip installed it (where you use your fork)

Comment: Actually, I want to modify and share the modules between my sites. I may or may not want to update them at all.

Comment: @frbry I was adding a part on a suggested workflow, let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: I think this is a good workflow too, and looks a lot like what I'm using right now. But I think I'm gonna use what Spike suggested because it looks simpler, at least, to me.

Comment: @frbry I think that the main advantage of this workflow is that deploying the code to additional servers can be done easily using pip, so no `$PYTONPATH` trick or symlinking is required. However, it's up to you what you decide in the end!

Comment: OK, but what if I want to work both on my web site and the module at the same time. I mean, how should I let my IDE to display the module directory among my source files?